# Assign a position value to row based on a SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the code below to get the total distance for teams that people have registered to and entered data, then assign a position to the team.

```
SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS position, ROUND(SUM(d.dist_activity_duration 
             * CASE 
                 WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 0 THEN s.activity_steps / 2000 
                 WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 1 THEN 1 
               END)
              ,2)   AS miles, t.team_name AS team_name
                    FROM distance d     
                    JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
                    JOIN activities a 
                    ON a.id = d.dist_activity_id
                    JOIN steps s
                    ON s.id = a.steps_id
                    JOIN members AS m   
                    ON d.member_id = m.id
                    JOIN teams AS t 
                    ON t.id = m.member_team_id
                    GROUP BY team_name 
                    ORDER BY miles DESC
```

The code above outputs the following results

```
position    miles    team_name
2           134.05   team 1
1           78.00    team 2
```

I would like position 1 to be assigned to the team with the highest miles, position 2 the 2nd highest team...and so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you would just use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY miles DESC) AS position, t.*
FROM (SELECT ROUND(SUM(d.dist_activity_duration *
                       CASE WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 0 THEN s.activity_steps / 2000 
                            WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 1 THEN 1 
                       END), 2)  AS miles, t.team_name AS team_name
      FROM distance d JOIN   
           activities a 
           ON a.id = d.dist_activity_id JOIN
           steps s
           ON s.id = a.steps_id JOIN
           members m   
           ON d.member_id = m.id JOIN
           teams t 
           ON t.id = m.member_team_id
      GROUP BY team_name 
     ) t
ORDER BY miles DESC;
```

Earlier versions of MySQL support variables but they do not play well with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.  The solution is a subquery (as above):

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS position, 
FROM (SELECT ROUND(SUM(d.dist_activity_duration *
                       CASE WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 0 THEN s.activity_steps / 2000 
                            WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 1 THEN 1 
                       END), 2)  AS miles, t.team_name AS team_name
      FROM distance d JOIN   
           activities a 
           ON a.id = d.dist_activity_id JOIN
           steps s
           ON s.id = a.steps_id JOIN
           members m   
           ON d.member_id = m.id JOIN
           teams t 
           ON t.id = m.member_team_id
      GROUP BY team_name 
      ORDER BY miles DESC
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params;
```

Comment: Just checked, our server is using version: 5.6. Is there an alternative to `row_number()`

Comment: The query returns
`position
2
3`

Comment: @user1809642 . . . The starting value should be `0` not `1`.

Comment: Starting the value at `0` returns `1 1` Not relating to starting at zero but the other columns aren't been returned.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) AS position, team_name, miles
FROM (SELECT ROUND(SUM(d.dist_activity_duration 
             * CASE 
                 WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 0 THEN s.activity_steps / 2000 
                 WHEN d.dist_is_distance = 1 THEN 1 
               END)
              ,2)   AS miles, t.team_name AS team_name
                    FROM distance d
                    JOIN activities a 
                    ON a.id = d.dist_activity_id
                    JOIN steps s
                    ON s.id = a.steps_id
                    JOIN members AS m   
                    ON d.member_id = m.id
                    JOIN teams AS t 
                    ON t.id = m.member_team_id
                    GROUP BY team_name 
                    ORDER BY miles DESC
 ) t CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT @rn := 0) params;
```